# How to call an action while AVAudio is playing at a specific time?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I would like to know how to call an action while the AVAudio is playing at a specific time.

Let's just say AVAudio hits "19 seconds" of playing then call an action of whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use AVPlayer to do so, AVPlayer has a method to add **addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval**. Notice that the time interval is 19, 1 which means that the block gets called every 19 seconds. You can make it such that you only perform your task for the first 19th second.

```
player = AVPlayer(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("UpTown", withExtension: "mp3")!)

player.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(CMTimeMake(19, 1), queue: dispatch_get_main_queue()) { time in
// perform your task here 
}

player.play()
```

Comment: It wont let me inherit the the AVPlayer class. I get an error "Multiple inheritance from classes 'UIViewController' and 'AVPlayer"

Comment: Why would you inherit AVPlayer ?